# Creating function with dynamic number of parameters

Tags: javascript

I want to create a function with dynamic number of parameters. I have a string array like

```
['param1','param2','param3']
```

and i need to create a function with this array

```
function test(param1,param2,param3){

}
```

is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `...args` ( [`rest parameter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions#Rest_parameters) ) to collect dynamic number of parameters

```js
function test(...args){
  console.log(args)
}
test(1,2,3,4)
test(1,2,3)
```

Comment: I tried this before but i guess i did it wrong. It's working now thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the array as a parameter

```js
var a=['param1','param2','param3']
function test(a){
console.log(a)
}
test(a)
```